# Ignoring Rows Containing Spaces When Importing Data Using Information Designer

Tags: sql, spotfire

I am trying to pull in data to Spotfire using an information link. Unfortunately, the calculated column does not end up containing any information. When I went back to reference the database that we are pulling from, there are records that contain spaces and some that do not, which is the information that I am interested in. Unfortunately, the empty rows are listed first so that is what Spotfire is referencing. Is there a way to ignore those records and pull in the necessary information instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spotfire can only produce visualizations that are as good as your data, so the first recommendation I have is to clean up your database so that these empty rows are no longer an issue. if the query powering the information link contains joins or complex SQL, I'd also suggest to make sure that this query is producing the correct results, and not accidentally joining in a weird way to create these empty rows.

but, assuming that's not a possibility, you have a couple of options:

1. using the **Filter Panel**, filter out all all rows that have an `(Empty)` value for a given column(s)
2. create a calculated column with an expression like `If([Some Column] is null, "IGNORE")` or some such. then either filter out those values using the **Filter Panel** or, on a per-visualization basis, add a **Data Limiting Expression** like `[Calculated Column You Just Created] is not null`

but again, this is a workaround; not a solution! if you pick a given column as your "null check," what if at some point a null value in that column is considered valid? if you cannot guarantee this will be the case, then you must fix your data at the data level.